# How to add newly created values in grid in extjs4

Tags: grid, extjs4

I am working in extjs4. I have gridview as-

```
{
xtype : 'grid',
            id : 'g2',
            store : 'qb.qbquestionoptionStore',
            columns : [ {
                text : 'Options',
                dataIndex : 'option',
                flex : 1
            }, {
                text : 'Answer',
                dataIndex : 'isAnswer',
                flex : 2.5
            },{
                header : 'edit',
                renderer : function(val) {
                    return '<a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>';
                }
            },
```

Above grid is showing option and isAnswer field. I am also having addoption button. When i am clicking on this button,its showing new option creation window as-
[image]on click of its save button i want to add thses new option and isAnswer fields value in above grid.I have retrived thses newly inserted field values by code-

```
var win = button.up('window');
        form = win.down('form');
        record = form.getRecord(), values = form.getValues();
    console.log(values.option);
    console.log(values.isAnswer);
```

So how to insert these values in above grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is separation between data and view in ExtJs. All data related stuff is handled via stores and models. So if you want to insert new row into the grid you should insert it into the corresponding store:

```js
var store = Ext.getStore('qb.qbquestionoptionStore');
store.add(form.getValues());
```

Comment: thanx sir for reply.. i have inserted lines as per you told. It is inserting these newly created entry in store. but does not showing this newly inserted entry on grid. So how to bring this entry on gridview also

Comment: @user1722857, Make sure that you insert into correct store (the one that connected to the grid). I use `Ext.getStore('qb.qbquestionoptionStore')` because I don't know your other code. You may use something like `grid.store`. Provided you inserted record into correct store the row should appear in the grid.